# Unable to import libraries in Python

Tags: python, path, environment-variables, windows-8.1, libraries

Yesterday, I accidentally deleted the Path variable but I think I restored them. I added Python path to it and I've got my python running through command prompt and also pip is working. However, I'm unable to import new modules to Python shell.
It comes up with the following error

```
enter code here
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
import wxPython
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wxPython'
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm missing? Maybe I didn't add the Path correctly?
here is what I have added

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts;
C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32;
C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python
```

Answer (score 0):

Also add `C:\Users\<your user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Libs;` to your path

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right version of Python, and the module is installed?

Comment: I'm able to import libraries I installed before I deleted the Path variable. When I try pip install wxPython again it shows that it's already been installed.